# Is there any social page such as Telegram, send whatsapp for medical consultation?

Tags: treatment

I am a doctor and would like to get opinion of my colleague or raise a question. So I am searching for an app that I can search for a speciality to ask my question or share my concern.

Comment: The question is more suitable at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use Figure 1. There's one caveat: cases are not grouped according to speciality; they're all on one page. However, the community is pretty decent and I'm pretty sure there are sufficient professionals that are able to address your concerns.

Description: "*Compelling medical cases for healthcare professionals. Used by healthcare professionals and students for education and collaboration.*"

https://figure1.com/